# Has many and has many through

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

Categories

```
id | title | parent_id
```

Products

```
id | title | category_id
```

The categories table self joins to make sub categories:

```
id | title | parent_id
 1   art     0
 2   sport   0
 3   brushes 1
 4   paints  1
 5   balls   2
```

Products then belong to a category, so a football product will belong to the balls category which is a sub category of sport.

I have a product and category model.

On the category model I have a hasManyThrough:

```
public function products()
{
   return $this->hasManyThrough('Product', 'Category', 'parent_id', 'category_id');
}
```

I call this via:

```
Category::with('products')->find($catId);
```

This all works, I can get all products within a category, the issue arrises when I need to get all products in a sub category, so with the data:

```
id | title | category_id
1    blue paint 4
2   red paint 4
3   fine brush 3
```

And calling:

```
Category::with('products')->find(1); //get all art products
```

I get blue paint, red paint and fine brush.

The problem occurs when I call a sub category:

```
Category::with('products')->find(4); //get all paints
```

I get nothing, I should get blue and red paint.

How can I call I solve this so that I can get all products for a parent or sub category?

Comment: Why are you using `hasManyThrough` and not simply: `hasMany('App\Product');`? I understand categories has subcategories, but is this important, for example to get a nested set.

Comment: If I use hasMany then I will not be able to get sub categories products.

Comment: You will get it, this `Category::with('products')->find(4);` will give back blue and red paint then. The only difference, that you won't get a nested set, like `category > subcategory > products`. Just `category > products`. But also subcategories will be in the result set, just not nested.

Comment: Yes the above will work for finding products under a sub category but not finding products under a category. How will it be able to find the paints if all I give it is the category 'Art', which has sub categories of paint and brushes and should return blue and red paint and a fine brush.

Comment: Ah, see your point now.

Comment: Thanks for your help anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to do this is to use two different relationships: one that requires the hasManyThrough() that you've already defined and one that is a simple hasMany():

```
public function subproducts()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Product');
}
```

That leaves the issue of having to add some "if ( $category->parent_id )" blocks in your controllers so that products() and subproducts() are called correctly...

Or you can try to get weird with your existing products() relationship and risk breaking some more basic Eloquent functionality in the process. In fact, it might not work at all. Perhaps something like this:

```
public function products()
{
    if ( $this->parent_id )
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Product');
    }
    else
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough('Product', 'Category', 'parent_id', 'category_id');
    }
}
```